# Shared Preferences differences

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

1) What is the difference between

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
```

and

```
getSharedPreferences(name, mode)
```

2) And what does each of them do?

3) And how can I make a  setting screen (Activity)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can have multiple SharedPreference files (so they are called SharedPreference**s**). The argument **`name`** of method `getSharedPreferences(name, mode)` specifies the the name of SharedPreference file to handle.

`PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)` returns the default SharedPreference file having default `name` and `mode`. Default name is based on your app's package name (as `packagename_preferences.xml`) and default mode is `MODE_PRIVATE`.

If you just want to use a single SharedPreferences file, `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)` is concise to use.

2) With `SharedPreferences` you can save some key-value data.

3) Your last question: *how to make a setting screen?* is too wide topic to answer here. However, I suggest that using `PreferenceActivity` or `PreferenceFragment` you can manage a SharedPreferences without handling SharedPreferences directly.